# How to create a fancy text in html with the help of css only

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a fancy text in HTML with the help of CSS only?
I am putting a link where you can see a better example of `fancy text`. https://www.ultimatebeaver.com/modules/fancy-text/

Comment: Define fancy. Use `font`.

Comment: You should be a lot more specific when you ask something. Also, StackOverflow is mostly a site where you ask people to help you solve a coding problem. You seem to be asking people to do something for you, which is frowned upon.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Yes. Its my bad. I should have more specific. 
Here is my recorrected question->>
I am putting a **link** where you can see a better example of `fancy text`. 
[https://www.ultimatebeaver.com/modules/fancy-text/]

Answer (score 0):

This is one neat CSS style that forces a background image to show through letters on the page.
    You can simply put any background in the .knockout class in css given in fiddle, also set different font and style as required.
See the fiddle

```css
.knockout {
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/christmas-lights-defocused-background-bokeh-gold-blue-picture-id613518332?k=6&m=613518332&s=612x612&w=0&h=Own5MdgJXjNhFd0YUyED1UP3mQsHeNhfML9F-DQYdYw=) -80px -80px;
  color: red;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

body{
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
 <div class="knockout"><a href="http://mksht.crisnoble.com" rel="Like cool shit? visit my site">gaurav</a></div>
```